# alternate ways of restricting asp.net website (other than by IP & password)

Tags: asp.net, security

I am currently IP restricting several asp.net websites using rewrite rules in my web.config that match our office IP range.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Block IP" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^403.html$" negate="true"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP}"
                    pattern="{MY OFFICE IP RANGE}"
                    negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="403.html" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The sites also require a username and password in order to view anything. But I'd like to have a second layer of protection like an ip block that prevents malicious activity. Since I often have people outside of our office that need to access the site, I can't always keep the IP block in place. What are some alternate ways of restricting access to asp.net websites that will work in a standard shared hosting environment? (something like VPN isn't an option since my webhost doesn't provide anything like that).

**Edit:** It has been brought to my attention that you can also configure the ip filtering using the native features of IIS rather than rewrite rules. Here is an example:

```
<security>
   <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">    <!-- this line allows everybody, except those listed below -->            
       <clear/>     <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->                
       <add ipAddress="83.116.19.53"/>     <!-- blocks the specific IP of 83.116.19.53  -->                
       <add ipAddress="83.116.119.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>     <!--blocks network 83.116.119.0 to 83.116.119.255-->                
       <add ipAddress="83.116.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0"/>     <!--blocks network 83.116.0.0 to 83.116.255.255-->                
       <add ipAddress="83.0.0.0" subnetMask="255.0.0.0"/>     <!--blocks entire /8 network of 83.0.0.0 to 83.255.255.255-->                
   </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

Edit: To clarify what I'm asking for - **I'm looking for OTHER ways to restrict access to a site. My ip filtering works fine. However it isn't ideal since my users sometimes access from ip addresses not on the list.**

Comment: Both firewalls and IIS itself have the ability to block incoming connections (including blocking by DNS name rather than IP): why do it with rewrite rule?

Comment: @Richard My hosting doesn't provide direct access to the firewall nor IIS. Is there a particular way to filter IP in IIS but using web.config?

Comment: I would check every possible configuration option provided by the hosting provider before I tried to do something in code.

Comment: IIS8 has [dynamic IP restrictions](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions).

Comment: Almost all of IIS's per site settings are put in `web.config`, I would be surprised if IP restrictions are not part of this (give it a try on a local virtual directory).)

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict/grant access to the IIS website or server in the IIS 7.5 MMC.  In IIS-> Authorization Rules you can granullarly add/deny access to the server by user account or group(s).